# HTTPS WCF Service - POST RemoteCertificateMismatch

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https, certificate

I have created a POST WCF Service. I have enabled it with HTTPS. I created a self signed certificate on IIS7, linked it with the service. When I try to call the service from another computre through fiddler, it gives me a warning popup shown in the image. If I click Yes service works fine, if I click No it wont go forward.[When I call the webservice from another computer through fiddler I get this popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPvrP.png). Certificate issuer name is suppose A.com

if I call the service on Host Computer with address: https://A.com/B.svc/PostData. It works fine with no popup.

If I call the service from any other computer with the IP or name of the computer it gives me the popup shown in the image.

Kindly please let me know what be reason.

Regards.

Comment: The self signed certificate that you have on server is trusted only on server. You need to trust it on client too.

Comment: Thank you Pepo, i think i should use third party certifcate like from verisign or any other instead of using self signed one.

Comment: Thank you everyone, sorry for the late response. Everything worked well!